# getting Warnings and console.error in each test cases in jest

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am using react native development and using jest for testing . and my cases my all are test cases passing but getting this error .

```
console.error node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:71

          Warning: Invalid argument supplied to oneOf, expected an instance of array.

        console.error node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:71

          Warning: In next release empty section headers will be rendered. In this release you can use 'enableEmptySections' flag to render empty section headers.

        console.error node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:71

          Warning: In next release empty section headers will be rendered. In this release you can use 'enableEmptySections' flag to render empty section headers

    in my all test cases
```

Answer (score 1):

try this 
enableEmptySections={true}